# How to make the value showing on a leaflet heatmap like this one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, heatmap

I'm attempting to use leaftlet.js, and heatmap.js (github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/) following [this example](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html)

But I want to show the value on the heatmap like [this crime page](http://www.trulia.com/real_estate/San_Francisco-California/) (with two options on: "Crime Risk Layers" and "Reported Incident Markers")

Here is the leaflet heatmap demo code of index.html (http:// raw.githubusercontent.com/pa7/heatmap.js/develop/examples/leaflet-heatmap/index.html). Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leaflet Heatmap Layer Plugin</title>
    <style>
      body, html { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;}
      body { font-family:sans-serif; }
      body * { font-weight:200;}
      h1 { position:absolute; background:white; padding:10px;}
      #map { height:100%; }
      .leaflet-container {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="/plugins/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Leaflet Heatmap Layer Example</h1>
   <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

        var testData = {
          max: 8,
          data: [{lat: 24.6408, lng:46.7728, count: 3},{lat: 50.75, lng:-1.55, count: 1},{lat: 52.6333, lng:1.75, count: 1},{lat: 48.15, lng:9.4667, count: 1},{lat: 52.35, lng:4.9167, count: 2},{lat: 60.8, lng:11.1, count: 1},{lat: 43.561, lng:-116.214, count: 1},{lat: 47.5036, lng:-94.685, count: 1},{lat: 42.1818, lng:-71.1962, count: 1},{lat: 42.0477, lng:-74.1227, count: 1},{lat: 40.0326, lng:-75.719, count: 1},{lat: 40.7128, lng:-73.2962, count: 2},{lat: 27.9003, lng:-82.3024, count: 1},{lat: 38.2085, lng:-85.6918, count: 1},{lat: 46.8159, lng:-100.706, count: 1},{lat: 30.5449, lng:-90.8083, count: 1},{lat: 44.735, lng:-89.61, count: 1},{lat: 41.4201, lng:-75.6485, count: 2},{lat: 39.4209, lng:-74.4977, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 1},{lat: 39.5593, lng:-105.006, count: 1},{lat: 45.2673, lng:-93.0196, count: 1},{lat: 41.1215, lng:-89.4635, count: 1},{lat: 43.4314, lng:-83.9784, count: 1},{lat: 43.7279, lng:-86.284, count: 1},{lat: 40.7168, lng:-73.9861, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 2},{lat: 35.5498, lng:-118.917, count: 1},{lat: 34.1568, lng:-118.523, count: 1},{lat: 39.501, lng:-87.3919, count: 3},{lat: 33.5586, lng:-112.095, count: 1},{lat: 38.757, lng:-77.1487, count: 1},{lat: 33.223, lng:-117.107, count: 1},{lat: 30.2316, lng:-85.502, count: 1},{lat: 39.1703, lng:-75.5456, count: 8},{lat: 30.0041, lng:-95.2984, count: 2},{lat: 29.7755, lng:-95.4152, count: 1},{lat: 41.8014, lng:-87.6005, count: 1},{lat: 37.8754, lng:-121.687, count: 7},{lat: 38.4493, lng:-122.709, count: 1},{lat: 40.5494, lng:-89.6252, count: 1},{lat: 42.6105, lng:-71.2306, count: 1},{lat: 40.0973, lng:-85.671, count: 1},{lat: 40.3987, lng:-86.8642, count: 1},{lat: 40.4224, lng:-86.8031, count: 4},{lat: 47.2166, lng:-122.451, count: 1},{lat: 32.2369, lng:-110.956, count: 1},{lat: 41.3969, lng:-87.3274, count: 2},{lat: 41.7364, lng:-89.7043, count: 2},{lat: 42.3425, lng:-71.0677, count: 1},{lat: 33.8042, lng:-83.8893, count: 1},{lat: 36.6859, lng:-121.629, count: 2},{lat: 41.0957, lng:-80.5052, count: 1},{lat: 46.8841, lng:-123.995, count: 1},{lat: 40.2851, lng:-75.9523, count: 2},{lat: 42.4235, lng:-85.3992, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 2},{lat: 25.6586, lng:-80.3568, count: 7},{lat: 33.0975, lng:-80.1753, count: 1},{lat: 25.7615, lng:-80.2939, count: 1},{lat: 26.3739, lng:-80.1468, count: 1},{lat: 37.6454, lng:-84.8171, count: 1},{lat: 34.2321, lng:-77.8835, count: 1},{lat: 34.6774, lng:-82.928, count: 1},{lat: 39.9744, lng:-86.0779, count: 1},{lat: 35.6784, lng:-97.4944, count: 2},{lat: 33.5547, lng:-84.1872, count: 1},{lat: 27.2498, lng:-80.3797, count: 1},{lat: 41.4789, lng:-81.6473, count: 1},{lat: 41.813, lng:-87.7134, count: 1},{lat: 41.8917, lng:-87.9359, count: 1},{lat: 35.0911, lng:-89.651, count: 1},{lat: 32.6102, lng:-117.03, count: 1},{lat: 41.758, lng:-72.7444, count: 1},{lat: 39.8062, lng:-86.1407, count: 1},{lat: 41.872, lng:-88.1662, count: 1},{lat: 34.1404, lng:-81.3369, count: 1},{lat: 46.15, lng:-60.1667, count: 1},{lat: 36.0679, lng:-86.7194, count: 1},{lat: 43.45, lng:-80.5, count: 1},{lat: 44.3833, lng:-79.7, count: 1},{lat: 45.4167, lng:-75.7, count: 2},{lat: 43.75, lng:-79.2, count: 2},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 3},{lat: 42.9833, lng:-81.25, count: 2},{lat: 44.25, lng:-79.4667, count: 3},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 2},{lat: 34.3667, lng:-118.478, count: 3},{lat: 42.734, lng:-87.8211, count: 1},{lat: 39.9738, lng:-86.1765, count: 1},{lat: 33.7438, lng:-117.866, count: 1},{lat: 37.5741, lng:-122.321, count: 1},{lat: 42.2843, lng:-85.2293, count: 1},{lat: 34.6574, lng:-92.5295, count: 1},{lat: 41.4881, lng:-87.4424, count: 1},{lat: 25.72, lng:-80.2707, count: 1},{lat: 34.5873, lng:-118.245, count: 1},{lat: 35.8278, lng:-78.6421, count: 1}]
        };

        var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
          'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
          }
        );

        var cfg = {
          // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
          "radius": 2,
          "maxOpacity": .8, 
          // scales the radius based on map zoom
          "scaleRadius": true, 
          // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
          // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries 
          //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
          "useLocalExtrema": true,
          // which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
          latField: 'lat',
          // which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
          lngField: 'lng',
          // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
          valueField: 'count'
        };


        var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);

        var map = new L.Map('map', {
          center: new L.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568),
          zoom: 4,
          layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
        });

        heatmapLayer.setData(testData);

        // make accessible for debugging
        layer = heatmapLayer;
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Another link that is relevant is this one using heatmap.js:

```
www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html
```

It shows the value when our mouse is hovering over a point.

Comment: Hey @osiris! Have you resolved this issue yet? I was having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use heatmapLayer._heatmap.getValueAt({ x: x, y: y}); to get the value using leaflet heatmap plugin.

Comment: but here the x and the y are different, like... a lot bigger numbers... and I think there is a radius problem because I allways get a 1 even if in my map that area is red.

Answer (score 0):

The way the Leaflet map is generating the heat map is from [interpolating](http://planet.botany.uwc.ac.za/nisl/GIS/spatial/chap_1_11.htm) the points to generate a raster.

Judging by the way the San Francisco crime map visually looks, being contiguous, it has a layer that represents city blocks or parcels with data associated with each feature, these are polygons and they are not directly generated from point data and **is not a heat map**. Rather, possibly there is a back-end process that spatially applies value too the parcels giving them a value that can visually be classified and rendered as a color. There are other methods to make what you see in the San Francisco map, but the point is, is that the polygon layer that represents the crime data is not interpolated the way a heat map is and is not processed into a raster.

Although they may both look visually the same the road to creating them are very much different.

If your data is point geometry a heat map might be your best option. If you want to represent the data with some polygon geometry (assuming that joining point data to polygon data is an accurate representation of the data) you will need a) polygon layer like city parcels b) a method of [spatially joining](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Spatial_Join) that data to the parcels or interpolating the data and assigning the cell values to the polygon features.

I'm not sure how fluent you are in the discipline of [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) but basically that is fundamentals of what we are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am working with discrete points as the `testData`  in the example of the questions. I add a relevant link in the original question.

Comment: So your question specifically targets mousing over cells and displaying values? If you are fine with using a heat map, the [example](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html) you linked would work fine with it I think.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. The question is that the example doesn't use a map as a baselayer. And it does't function for zoom and drag of the map.

Comment: It seems that both examples are using the same heatmap object, Did you try creating the `heatmap` object from the first example and then do `var value = heatmapInstance.getValueAt({ x: x,  y: y});`

Comment: I have tried that. But the question is that the heatmapInstance the example uses doesn't have getValueAt method, which is provided in heatmap.js, but not in leaflet-heatmap.js

Comment: @Osiris I'm facing the same problem. 2019 and leaflet-heatmap doesn't have the getValueAt method yet. I wonder if you solved it already and could give me a hand, please